# How to write mysqli query in php function?

Tags: php, mysqli

It worked well with mysql, but how to write it with mysqli?

This is my connection string :

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die("Cannot connect mysql");
```

this is what i get-> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\pagination\function.php.

```
function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?')
{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM $query";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($query));
}
```

Comment: see this link for proper syntax http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in your `$db` using the global identifier, and then as [Florian Lefèvre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4726998/florian-lef%C3%A8vre) has said add the link to your `mysqli_query()`.

```
function pagination($query, $per_page = 10,$page = 1, $url = '?')
{
    global $db;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM $query";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, $query));
}
```

Comment: @suonsamoun no problems glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You forget the link: `mysqli_query($db, $query)`
EDIT: First thing to do, read the doc :) http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I also do that but it say-> Undefined variable: db

Comment: How can i include my connection file in that function?

Comment: Where are you doing mysqli_connect ?

Comment: Florian Lefevre my connection string is in another file, but in the same folder with function.php file